# Open Office Calc lookup vlookup

Tags: openoffice-calc, vlookup, lookup

I am trying to return a value to a cell, columns `C` to `H` depending on what is chosen in the drop down in column `B`.

[image]

The figures I need to return are held on a separate sheet .

[image]

Any help with this would be great as I am now pulling my hair out trying to use `VLOOKUP` and `LOOKUP`

Comment: Solved: found out where i was going wrong
trying to use excel formulas in an open office calc.
forgot to replace "," with ";"

Comment: Commas will work in LibreOffice but not in OpenOffice, depending on the locale.

Comment: I have OpenOffice and that's where all my problems lay. Now onto bigger problems

Answer (score 0):

If sheets are named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" then enter the following formula in cell C2:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1.$B2,Sheet2.$A$2:$G$61,COLUMN()-1,0)
```

Now drag the formula down the rest of column B.  Then drag the selected cells over to column G.

[image: spreadsheet result]

Documentation: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP

Comment: Have to replace commas with semi colon on OpenOffice calc. That's where problem lay